# How to compile stylus config to js object

Tags: stylus

I need to share a config between stylus and react. How can I pull stylus variables to js?

I know I can use json in stylus, but JSON is static, you can not define a setting in it which is calculated using another setting. So I want to reuse stylus variables in my react app.

Answer (score 0):

Stylus supports Javascript API. In fact, you can get Stylus as npm package.

You don't need to convert anything. Take a look at docs: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/js.html
Make use of `stylus-vars` package to inject config into `.styl` files. Here, in docs, is complete example https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylus-vars

Comment: stylus-vars is broken